# Error "/usr/bin/env:'node': No such file or directory" in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: node.js, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a pipeline created in Jenkins with the following configuration for a Nodejs application:

```
pipeline {
agent any
stages {
    stage('Build') {
        steps {
            nodejs(nodeJSInstallationName: 'Node8') {
                sh 'npm install'
            }
        }
    }
    stage('Test') {
        steps {
            nodejs(nodeJSInstallationName: 'Node8') {
                sh 'npm run test'
            }
        }
    }
    stage('Deploy') {
        steps {
            nodejs(nodeJSInstallationName: 'Node8') {
                sh 'npm run start'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

But the execution of 'npm' is failing, which gives me the following error:

```
+ npm install
/usr/bin/env:'node': No such file or directory
```

I installed Jenkins on my server using Docker (image jenkins/jenkins:lts) and I installed the NodeJS plugin in Jenkins.

I created the Node tooling in this way:

[image]

Do you know what may be happening?

A greeting.

Comment: How did you installed nodejs inside jenkins container?

Comment: I just added it to the post. I did not manually install Node on the Jenkins machine, but I installed the NodeJS plugin for Jenkins.

Comment: I guess you have to use the [`tool`](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#-tool-%20use%20a%20tool%20from%20a%20predefined%20tool%20installation) step to first install the tool.

Comment: I have already installed the NodeJS plugin and I have added an installation to use in the pipeline (Node8) from the section of the Global Tool Configuration menu. Do you need to do something else?

Comment: same issue! any luck here @JoseSabater? you can try the scripted pipeline in the meantime
https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/NodeJS+Plugin#NodeJSPlugin-Pipeline

Comment: I have not managed to solve it yet @Theo. If you find the solution share it here, please. Thanks

Comment: No luck buddy :( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51416409/jenkins-env-node-no-such-file-or-directory

Comment: @JoseSabater check my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51416409/jenkins-env-node-no-such-file-or-directory/51643415#answer-51643415 maybe we have the same case

Answer (score 1):

Try this

*sudo ln -sf "$(which node)" /usr/bin/node*

Answer (score 0):

sudo ln -s /var/lib/jenkins/tools/jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation/node/bin/node /usr/bin/node

Comment: Please don't post same answer on multiple old post