# Jenkins - env: ‘node’: No such file or directory

Tags: node.js, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a jenkins server that is configured using
https://github.com/shierro/jenkins-docker-examples/tree/master/05-aws-ecs

I am running a [blue ocean](https://github.com/jenkinsci/blueocean-plugin) pipeline using a simple Jenkinsfile and the [jenkins NodeJS plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/NodeJS+Plugin)

```
pipeline { 
  agent any 

  tools {
    nodejs 'node10'
  }

  stages {
    stage ('Checkout Code') {
      steps {
        checkout scm
      }
    }
    stage ('Install dependencies') {
      steps {
        sh "echo $PATH"
        sh "npm install"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I made sure to add the **node10** global tool as well w/c is used above
[image]

When the pipeline gets to the script `sh "npm install"` i am running through this error
[image]

this is the output of the command `echo $PATH`
[image]

so i think it's not a path issue

Also, it also wasn't able to add the global package
[image]

More info that might help:

- Docker Jenkins server: `FROM jenkins/jenkins:2.131-alpine`
- Blue ocean version: 1.7.0
- NodeJS Plugin: 1.2.6
- Multiple server restarts already

**Any ideas why the jenkins server does not know where node is?**

Big thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the node binary in your path?

Comment: @iJos yes it is. i accessed the docker image and i see `npm` & `node` on /var/jenkins_home/tools/jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation/node10/bin

Comment: I tried a slightly reduced code snippet on my local Jenkins (w/o docker) - and it worked. Maybe something's wrong with the docker setup? In the build log, did you see that node actually was downloaded and unzipped into that very folder where the path points to?

Comment: @JoergS thanks for the insight - that's a possibility, maybe the alpine version is not compatible with the plugin? There's no build log shown to download on the pipeline step, but i see that the node executable is already downloaded on path `/var/jenkins_home/tools/jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation/node10/bin`. i'll try the image jenkins/jenkins:lts & get back

Comment: Hey @JoergS you can post an answer so I can give you some credit :)

Comment: @Theo: Thanks for the suggestion. However I feel like it was more like a combined effort :) You may upvote my comment if you like. Think that’s enough credit for me on that one.

Comment: @JoergS as you say mate :) Thanks again! really appreciate your help

Comment: Thanks for posting the very detailed questions. I was able to fix my issue just by seeing a good configured environment and description.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thanks to @JoergS for some insight! The culprit in this case is: **using alpine image as the docker base**. So switching from `jenkins/jenkins:2.131-alpine` to `jenkins/jenkins:2.131` solved the NodeJS plugin issue.

Comment: My issue ended up being with the jenkinsci/blueocean image. I was able to just replace that image with jenkins/jenkins:lts and the NodeJS plugin began working as expected.

Answer (score 2):

I have faced the same issue with jenkinsci/blueocean. I have resolved this by installing nodejs with below command(inside docker) not as jenkins plugin

`apk add nodejs`

Comment: I am also running jenkinsci/blueocean and facing the same issue. Can you please provide me the solution in detail? It would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the same issue with jenkinsci/blueocean. No jenkins nodejs plugin needed.

```
pipeline { 
  agent any 

  stages {
    stage ('Checkout Code') {
      steps {
        checkout scm
      }
    }
    stage ('Install dependencies') {
      steps {
        sh "apk add nodejs"
        sh "echo $PATH"
        sh "npm install"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a symbolic link like this:

sudo ln -s /var/lib/jenkins/tools/jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation/node/bin/node /usr/bin/node

Answer (score 0):

I want to highlight  Mitch Downey's comment, it can't be just a comment because after spending 4 hours with no solution this comment helped me to resolve the solution

> My issue ended up being with the jenkinsci/blueocean image. I was able
> to just replace that image with jenkins/jenkins:lts and the NodeJS
> plugin began working as expected